# IIS Active Directory Autologin without Popup

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, iis-6, login

There are similar question to this on stackoverflow and I have pretty much posted the same question there, with no responses.

My scenario is this: I would like, when users hit an internal site (ASP Classic, IIS 6, windows server 2003), it to autologin and work out who they are, based on their Active Directory record WITHOUT a popup asking them to input their username and password. Using Anonymous Auth within IIS means that LOGON_USER within ASP outputs the Administrator user. Turning anonymous off means I get the popup.

As they have already logged into windows, is there a way for it to work out who they are, and not require them to input a username and password again.

I have got the AD integration within ASP cracked. So i can read their record and everything I wanted to do. Just need to stop it from asking for a Username and Password.

Thanks in advance, James

**EDIT** As per CJM's request:

- I have tried the following combinations within IIS: Set Anonymous
  access **ON** with Integration Windows auth **ON** I get (As
  expected): No login box (User String:
  CN=IUSR_WIN2K3R2EE,CN=Users...etc)
- Set Anonymous access **OFF** with Integration Windows auth **ON** I get (As expected): A login box, I login as User: jameshaley (User String: CN=James Haley,CN=Users...etc)
- Set Anonymous access **OFF** with Integration Windows auth **ON** and Digest Auth for Win domain servers **ON** I also get (As expected): A login box, I login as User: jameshaley (User String: CN=James Haley,CN=Users...etc)
- Set Anonymous access **OFF** with Integration Windows auth **ON** and Digest Auth for Win domain servers **ON** I also get (As expected): A login box, I login as User: jameshaley (User String: CN=James Haley,CN=Users...etc)
- Set Anonymous access **OFF** with Integration Windows auth **ON**, Digest Auth for Win domain servers **ON** and Basic Auth *ON* I again, also get (As expected): A login box, I login as User: jameshaley (User String: CN=James Haley,CN=Users...etc)

I have tried every combination posible, and it just doesn't want to work :(

Comment: In short, yes it is possible. In fact, I have done it myself in the past. However it can fraught with problems and complications in my experience. Perhaps you should outline the steps you have taken to implement this - perhaps we can spot a problem.

Comment: Duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7983424/2291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable Windows Authentication and disable Anonymous access.
Logon popup window appears because in your browser the site is not trusted for windows authentication. 
See this article to enable Windows Authentication in FF
http://www.1stbyte.com/2008/03/15/automatic-windows-authentication-with-firefox-networkautomatic-ntlm-authtrusted-uris/
and this article to enable it in IE
http://www.1stbyte.com/2008/03/15/ie7-fails-to-automatically-authenticate-with-enable-integrated-windows-authentication-checked/

Comment: Had a problem with the site being recognised as an intranet site

Comment: @sparkyfied: What does "had a problem" mean? Are you saying _now_ you have the problem, or that was part of the solution for you?

Comment: Sorry! Yes! It is now sorted!